# Smart contract successfully transfers money, but they are not present in my wallet

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, ethers.js

I am trying to transfer 1 ether to an account. Money are sent from the frontend using ethers library(i put amount of eth in msg.value). Smart contract successfully receives it and immediately trasnfers them to the owner of the contract(me in this case). No errors, no warnings, transfer is successful but i don't see them in my metamask wallet. I only see -(1eth + gas) that i sent. Function that i call is payable and it should be fine. Any suggestions?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DypP8.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwlI4.png)

Comment: The screenshot looks like from Etherscan. Can you post the transaction detail URL?

Comment: Sure, here's the full url: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x9f7681961a38f9cf3b48f968c18c7cb873ffe387699dad898fc4357c0a92b5c8

Comment: it's a different transaction this time. But the money are not sent to my wallet anyways(though transfer is successful yet again)

Comment: Your wallet in MetaMask is the `0x1d2fd8...`? Are you switched to the Rinkeby network in MetaMask?

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help. I solved it. I needed a `withdraw onlyOnwer` method to be able to transfer funds to myself. Not sure though why i couldn't do that immediately in the method called on the frontend.